# C# How do I get an argument variable from a void in a different class?

Tags: c#

Say I have the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void myVoid(int number)
    {
        //insert code here.
    }
}
```

Later in MyClass, the void will be called, and `number` will be a random value.

In a different class, without making a new variable in MyClass, will it be possible to receive `number` from myVoid?

I'm thinking the answer is something like:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    MyClass myclass = null;
    public void Start()
    {
        int theNumber = myclass.myVoid.GetFirstArgument();
    }
}
```

But I don't know.

Comment: use a property (getter) to keep the number you passed in the MyClass myVoid method so that you can retrieve it later if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If AnotherClass holds a reference on MyClass (handed in via Constructor or because it created the other instance) it can access all public fields and properties of the MyClass instance.

There are some ways to disolve the normaly strict public/private options: Protected, friends, internals. But you should be sure that this is what you want.

Maybe what you wanted to do was actually just create a property? myVoid looks like it might be a set function. And it sounds like you just want to control the get functions/backing fields accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property in MyClass that is set within myVoid method, assigning it the value of number. Then you can get the value of number in AnotherClass by accessing that property in MyClass.